# Microsoft Graph API change notifications for todoTask

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, change-notification

Microsoft Graph API has provisions for accessing todoTask - it does not however have application level permissions (those are listed as "not supported"). How would an application implement creating / updating tasks and getting notifications for multiple users? Seems like a glaring hole in the api framework

Answer (score 0):

Yes application level permissions are not yet supported. Please file a user voice [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) for your ask so that it could be considered in future.

Thanks!

Comment: The feature mentioned in the answer refers to plannerTasks - not quite the same as the todoTasks, which are directly accessible via the outlook (at least that is my understanding).

Comment: @BobRabinowitz Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited the answer. Please file a user voice. Thanks!